# Counting and Ordering Systems in Languages/Cultures

Tags: .net, numbers

Is there a native .NET way to look up numbers in various counting/ordering systems, languages and cultures. For example, I have the numbers 1, 2, and 3. If I want these in Arabic, I can get them with `NumberInfo`, e.g.

```
Public Sub PrintNumbers()
    Dim currentCI As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("ar-LB")
    Dim nfi As NumberFormatInfo = currentCI.NumberFormat
    Dim nativeDigitList As String() = nfi.NativeDigits
    For i = 1 To 3
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", i, nativeDigitList(i)))
    Next
End Sub
```

Which prints: 1: ١, 2: ٢, 3: ٣

This is a good start at what I'm looking for, but I'm looking for a much more complete system of producing native digits (and other counters) for other counting systems in languages/cultures.

Native digits, as in .NET using the same code for Chinese ("zh-CN") produces 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3. But I'm looking for  1: 一, 2: 二, 3: 三. Or even Chinese Financial: 1: 壹, 2: 贰, 3: 叁. (Note: *Chinese samples in Simplified*).

In English, we also use Roman numerals: 1: I, 2: II, 3: III.

There are non-numeric counting systems as well, such as 1: A, 2: B, 3: C in English, ت،ث‌ in Arabic or the Abjad system in Arabic: ،‌ج،‌د‌ .

I'm sure there are many other ways to count across various languages, scripts and cultures. The `NativeDigits` array doesn't provide for counting above 9 and doesn't offer other cultural/script counting systems.

So the question is: do you know of any way to achieve this in .NET that I may have not been able to find or has work on an open-source project been done that would allow me to specify a culture (like "fa-IR"), a number (like "49") and a counting system supported by that culture?

So if it was "en-US", "27" and "abc-system", it would give me "aa".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless a better answer comes along, the best I could find for counting lists is at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists. Although not .NET, I can be implemented in .NET fairly simply.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at this before, and have found the same thing as you have.

The closes you can do is use `NativeDigits` to translate western numerals to their equivalents - there is nothing more comprehensive built into the BCL, nor do I know of any library that implements such a thing.

Comment: Part of the issue with doing this is I'm not going to know how each language/cultural implements its counting. For example, I may make the mistake of implementing 4, 5, 6 in Persian as ٤, ٥, ٦ when that is not what it is at all, it is ۴, ۵, ۶. Those are the only 3 digits in 0-9 Farsi that are different from Arabic. Another example would that 1001 in Chinese-displayed-counting wouldn't be 一千零一, but rather 一〇〇一。 I just happen to know these two languages. But when we start talking about Hebrew, Thai, Hindi and other languages/cultures, I wouldn't be able to create any kind of mapping system.

Comment: @Otaku - As a Hebrew speaker myself I can tell you that Hebrew counting gets as complicated as Roman numerals... It would be great to be able to pass an `int` and `CultureInfo` to a function and get a textual representation, but I don't know of any library that does that.